# how product Reviews & Ratings can be done in SAP Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new in Hybris. In my project existing product's user Reviews & Ratings is maintain by Gigya. Is there any facility in hybris that we can maintain product's user Reviews & Ratings with in the hybris. so that we can get rid of Gigya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The **customerreview** extension provides functionality enabling front end users to give review and rating on offered products.

Customer reviews are built on top of the **customerreview** extension. The features offered include customer reviews and ratings that can be moderated.

For more details check [this](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8acd9bc386691014a4fc9ae69914f84a.html)